# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in Chrome when Referencing react-table

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, react-proptypes, react-table

I'm new to react. Having a very weird issue referencing `react-table` in Chrome. As soon as I add import statement to my page: `import ReactTable from 'react-table';` and then perform any action on ANY part of the page or re-render, I get a weird syntax error in Chrome on this line: `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'` in `propTypes.js`.

This error visible in dev tools source only. Nothing in console. When hovered over it states `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"`. 
This happens in Chrome only and preventing any debugging but doesn't cause any other errors and functionality seems to be unaffected.

It has something to do with `'react-table'` package because as soon as I remove it's `import`, everything is fine and anything that I do on other pages doesn't have any affect on this error. When I tried to view the `propTypes.js` I can't even find this line there. Can someone at least point me to how to troubleshoot this?

Chrome is the main browser for customer base and it's essential for my development.

- Chrome version: Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit),
- node: 6.11.13
- "react": "^16.2.0".
- "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
- "react-table": "^6.8.0",

I have been banging my head with this one and searching online for a while now with no result. Please help! Any tip is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you add `propTypes.js` and file which you import `import ReactTable from 'react-table';` ?

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. Any luck?

Comment: @Jeff - no luck yet. After spending quite sometime trying to make it work, I abandoned it and now building my own component based on MUI v.1.0 basic table. Really disappointed in MUI table components that I've found out there.

Comment: @hendrathings - modified to add both files versions.

Comment: @lentyai,  `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"` means that you have missing something, like `;` or `)` parenthesis.  Recheck your code

Comment: @lentyai can you post your code the file in which you `import ReactTable from 'react-table'`?